# Searching for ContentType name works, but not for ID/GUID

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, pnp

I have a webpart solution that searches contentType via name like:

```
ContentType: My_CT
```

I want to change this and use the CTs GUID, like:

```
ContentTypeId: 0x01007B8C5278BB810F499CC61F62C6B14FC5
```

But it does not generate any results as expected, and I have tried the query inside SharePoints modern search and it works for CT name, but not for GUID there as well.

How come, and how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `*` at the end of `Content Type Id`

Please try below query, it should work:

```
ContentTypeId:0x01007B8C5278BB810F499CC61F62C6B14FC5*
```